# Primefaces Wizard next button functionality

Tags: primefaces, wizard

I need to implement an aditional button in a wizard that when the user click on it the component go to the next step without select next button.
And only in this step the next button is hide.

The code I propose is:

```
<p:commandLink title="select and go to next step" process="@this"
               action="#{controller.selectPerson}" ajax="true"
               value="select and go to next step"
               oncomplete="PF('wizard').next();">
    <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{person}"
                                 target="#{controller.selectedPerson}"/>
</p:commandLink>
```

Thank yo for your help

Comment: where is the table that you talk about ?!?

Comment: Thank you for your question, the button would be in the table like a selection, I edit my question because I only need a extra button that call the next function from wizard

Comment: did you try to use a `<p:commandButton onclick="PF('wizard').next();" />`

Comment: @YagamiLight Thank you for your response, Yes I tried with PF('wizard').next(); the webpage refresh but don't pass the next step in component.

Comment: Using firebug console give me an error: TypeError: PF(...) is undefined.